# How to do a remote PSSession and run a script in the remote desktop?

Tags: java, powershell

When I try to connect and run a PowerShell script manually from CMD I can do it, but when I try to do the same in my Java code an error is displayed, my code for the connection is this:

```java
String command = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell C:\\scr.ps1";

Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();
String line;
System.out.println("Standard Output:");
BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    powerShellProcess.getInputStream()));
while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
stdout.close();
//En caso de error se obtiene
System.out.println("Standard Error:");
BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    powerShellProcess.getErrorStream()));
while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
stderr.close();
System.out.println("Done");
```

Before I tried to put all the commands in a the command string, but that didn't work, so I decided to put it in a script. The script contains this:

```bsh
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "pass" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.management.Automation.PSCredential("user", $pass)
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName User-Pc -Credential $cred ;

dir
```

but the last command `dir` is done in mi local desktop not in the remote one, I debug and I don't find any error the script works, the connection was done but I don't understand why the `dir` command doesn't execute in the remote desktop, somebody have any idea of what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enter-PSSession` is for *interactive* use. For *non-interactive* command execution use `Invoke-Command`:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer 'User-Pc' -Scriptblock {
    Get-ChildItem
} -Credential $cred
```